# Refresh the screen every time you open it

Tags: flutter

How to make an api request every time the screen opens? Now, after the first opening, the screen is saved, and you can update it only by pressing a button or swiping up. How to do this automatically, so that every time you open the screen, a request to the API is executed and the screen is updated?

I tried to use need_resume, but it also doesn’t work as I need it

Answer (score 1):

Turn it into a StatefulWidget and use initState
The framework will call this method exactly once for each State object it creates.
More information check the [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/initState.html)

```
@override
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // API here
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work for me.
This method works the first time the screen opens, and then the state of this screen is saved. If you go from BottomNavigationBar to the next screen and then go back to this one, then not a single method is executed. It just opens the saved state

Comment: Is that because you're using automatickeepaliveclientmixin?

Answer (score 0):

There's a specific package for such a thing. The package name is [after_layout](https://pub.dev/packages/after_layout). This Package was developed by the official Flutter community.

It's mainly used in asynchronous functions calling while opening the screen. It's the best approach because it does not disrupt the initial widget-building stage. While the initState is not for asynchronous calling.

Sample code:

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> with AfterLayoutMixin<HomePage> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Placeholder();
  }

  @override
  FutureOr<void> afterFirstLayout(BuildContext context) async {
    // Make your API call here. It's the safest area & it's a greatest approach.
    return Future<void>.value();
  }
}
```

Comment: Cannot be used together with AutoTabsScaffold when clicking on BottomNavigationBarItem